# Loose Scope in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have a multiple tab Html page . On one tab i have add 3 input box and an add button. Whenever the add button is clicked the data to be added into a grid below. But scope is not accessing these variables. Attaching my code below :

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" 
                ng-class="{active:isActiveTab(tab.url)}" 
                ng-click="onClickTab(tab)">{{tab.title}}</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="mainView">
            <div ng-include="currentTab"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type ="text/javascript" id="one.tpl.html">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
                ng-model="names" />{{name}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Employees</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="employees"
                ng-model="employeess" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Headoffice</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="headoffice"
                ng-model="headoffices" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">                                
        <div style="padding-left:110px">
            <input type="button" value="Add"  ng-click="addRow()" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Name
        </th>
        <th>Employees
        </th>
        <th>Head Office
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="company in companies">
        <td>{{company.name}}
        </td>
        <td>{{company.employees}}
        </td>
        <td>{{company.headoffice}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
  </script>


    <script type="text/ng-template" id="two.tpl.html">
        <div id="viewTwo">
            <h1>View Two</h1>
            <p>Test 2</p>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="three.tpl.html">
        <div id="viewThree">
            <h1>View Three</h1>
            <p>Test 3</p>
        </div>

    </script>
</div>






<script>


var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {


$scope.companies = [];



$scope.tabs = [{
            title: 'One',
            url: 'one.tpl.html'
        }, {
            title: 'Two',
            url: 'two.tpl.html'
        }, {
            title: 'Three',
            url: 'three.tpl.html'
    }];



$scope.currentTab = 'one.tpl.html';


$scope.onClickTab = function(tab) {
    $scope.currentTab = tab.url;
}
 $scope.isActiveTab = function(tabUrl) {
        return tabUrl == $scope.currentTab;
    } 


$scope.addRow = function(){ 
$scope.companies.push({ 'name':$scope.names, 'employees': $scope.employeess, 'headoffice':$scope.headoffices });

    $scope.names='';
    $scope.employeess='';
    $scope.headoffices='';

} 
});
</script>

<style>
#tabs ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#tabs li {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    margin: 3px 3px 0px 3px;
    padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    color: #696969;
}
#mainView {
    border: 1px solid black;
    clear: both;
    padding: 0 1em;
}
.active {
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #000;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Following variables are not accessible in scope :

```
$scope.names
$scope.employeess
$scope.headoffices
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because ng-template creates child scope, so you can basically do one of 2 things:

- Access properties via $parent (like $parent.employeess). Example:https://plnkr.co/edit/2LLakRumEB25wyNhNmDg?p=preview)
- Define object for new item like below.

Example: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/sFkim5WwN5ffPsWtdcDP?p=preview

```
$scope.newRow = {
  names: '',
  employeess: '',
  headoffices: ''
}
```

And access them via the same prefix:

```
ng-model="newRow.employeess"
```

Explanation:

Scopes have common structure, where $parent property is the parent scope e.t.c up to $rootScope.

When you're using ng-template it creates a new child scope, so the values, assigned within it are stored in the child scope and not in $parent (your controllers scope). The values you're searching for are in child scope because ng-model works in current scope. So you need to make sure that ng-model knows which scope to write. It can be done via $parent parameter or within object. As for 2nd option - the reason is simple. Object value can't be assigned when object is undefined, so search goes to upper level and so on.